# Use swiperjs with Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, swiper.js

I want to use swiperjs on my vue.js project but I don't know how to import it in. I've try import ***css*** and ***js*** file in ***pluginglobal.js*** but it doesn't work. Any idea how to import it in? since the official site doesn't provide instruction for vue.js.

Thank you for taking your time reading this.

Comment: run `npm i swiper` then `import Swiper from 'swiper'` in your component and now you can use swiper with `new Swiper('.classname', {...options})`